# SpraedPDFBundle generate 2 pages

Tags: symfony, pdf, twig, bundle

I don't know if someone has used this bundle before (SpraedPDFGenerator) but it appears that it's generating 2 pages while the "data" is shown only in the first page and the second is just blank.
Can it be just a bug or it has something to do with my twig.html?

Thanks.

This is my twig:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('css/css.css') }} " media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tag-box tag-box-v2 box-shadow shadow-effect-1" style="float: left;">
        {% for oField in Info %}
            <div>{{ oField.inf }}</div>
            <div>{{ oField.inf  }}</div>
            <div>{{ oField.inf  }}</div>
            <div>{{ inf  }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="tag-box tag-box-v2 box-shadow shadow-effect-1" style=" float:right; height: 48px;  padding-right:125px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: -12px;">
        {% for oField in Info %}
            <div><b>text</b> {{ oField.inf }}</div>
            <div><b>text</b> {{ oField.inf }}</div>
            <div><b>text</b> {{ oField.inf }}</div>
            <div><b>text</b> {{ oField.inf }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="padding-top: 250px;  margin-right: 25px;">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>inf</th>
                    <th>inf</th>
                    <th>inf</th>
                    <th>inf</th>
                    <th>inf</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for oProd in Info %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ oProd.Info }}</td>
                        <td >{{ oProd.Info }}</td>
                        <td >{{ oProd.Info }}</td>

                        <td>15%</td>
                        <td>{{ oProd.Info }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
                    <td>{{ total }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's my controller:

```
$html =   $this->renderView('FrontendBundle:Name:name.html.twig', array(
        'data' => data
    ));
return new Response($pdfGenerator->generatePDF($html),200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'inline; filename="out.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your twig.html and the call of the PDFGenerator?

Comment: is everything rendered correctly if you return new Response($html)?
or is data missing.

Comment: there's no data missing however if I disable CSS I get all my data in one page. could it be something with css like a wrong "padding"?

Comment: this is what it looks like. Since you can hardly debug using the pdf view, I'd suggest coloring the backgrounds of markup areas, to see what is happening in pdf view.

Also, have a look at print css like "page-break-before: avoid;" and similar.

Comment: yes that was it I just had to modify the body height to less than 30cm. thanks for your time.